# How to I setup auth0 in angular so that the returned token can be used for MULTIPLE apis?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

For example, I have an Angular 5 application. And 2 different microservices using asp.net core 2.1. 
What would the configuration look like at the client side , for example, would it look like the following? :

```
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
clientID: environment.clientID,
domain: environment.domain,
responseType: 'token id_token',
scope: "openid profile API1 API2",
redirectUri: environment.callbackURL
```

});

Can someone provide and example of this configuration object to satisfy the criteria of allowing the token to be valid when sent to two different apis?
The issue I am facing is that I can setup a SINGLE working client-api, but this requires me to bind the angular client auth0 code to a single api since it has awareness of a variable 'audience', such as

```
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
clientID: environment.clientID,
domain: environment.domain,
audience: environment.audience,
responseType: 'token id_token',
redirectUri: environment.callbackURL
```

});

But the problem with this is that the configuration at the client is now api specific ( since it has audience prop), whereas I need to configure the client to allow it to make requests to MULTIPLE DIFFERENT apis.  Any help is appreciated. I feel like all that is needed is a valid sample setup of the object

```
auth0.WebAuth
```

The red flag to me in setting up my application was when I noticed that , based on the recommended approach, It was recommended that I hardcode a SINGLE Audience property, which doesnt make sense. If I bind the client to 1 and only 1 audience, then I cant add more, right?

Ive read the following links
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9

and I have also tested against two apis, and when I configure the SPA client (angular in this case) with the single audience property, only 1 api authenticates properly with the returned token in the callback.

Ive also asked a similar question here
https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-webapi-samples/issues/13#issuecomment-416036439

In other words, when a single AUDIENCE property is specified in the angular app, the token that is received on the callback is only valid for 1 api, the 1 specified in the audience property. Calling an endpoint on the 2nd api fails with that given token.

My only workaround to this confusion is to use the same value for options.Audience in BOTH asp.net core apis, specifically here in startup.cs

```
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
            options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
        });
```

which doesnt seem right since this value should be distinct per microservice/api.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like actually I cannot accomplish creating two seperate audiences, and instead have to use my workaround of using the same audience.

https://community.auth0.com/t/access-tokens-with-multiple-audiences/9911

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/represent-multiple-apis

here is another good answer as well

https://community.auth0.com/t/webauth-audience-multiple-apis-and-scopes/7063/2

Comment: For reference, I have looked into this and come to the same conclusion (using the same links you mentioned above).

Comment: @BRass, thank you. Please upvote if you feel this is helpful. Thank you.